# Getting the error unorderable types: int() >= list()

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to write the python code for mergesort and i unable to locate the error.

```
import math
t = int(input())

def merge(lf,rf):
    p=0
    q= 0    
    b=[]
    for i in range(len(rf)+len(lf)):    
        if (p>=len(lf)):
            b.append(rf[q:])
            break
        elif (q>=len(rf)):
            b.append(lf[p:])
            break
        elif (lf[p]>=rf[q]):
            b.append(rf[q])
            q=q+1
        else:
            b.append(lf[p])
            p=p+1
    return b


def sort(a):
    if (len(a)>1):
        mid = int(len(a)/2)
        lf=a[:mid]
        rf=a[mid:]
        lf=sort(lf) 
        rf=sort(rf)
        a=merge(lf,rf)
        print (a)
    return a

for i in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    a = [0]*n
    for j in range(n):
        a[j]=int(input())
    sort(a)
    print(a)
```

Comment: Which line raises the unorderable types error? In short, you comparing an integer to a list of integers, and that isn't allowed in Python 3. You probably intended forgot to index a list reference (e.g, `x > l[i]` instead of `x >= l[i]` Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The last `print` statement in your for loop prints the original list, and I am unsure if that is intended. If you want to print the sorted list instead, you will have to reassign `a` to the return of `sort`.

Comment: When your Python code throws an error it's _really_ helpful if you can paste the _entire_ traceback error message into your question, so we can see exactly what's causing the error. (Put it into a codeblock, to preserve formatting).

Comment: @Leon thanks for mentioning that actually i was was thinking about the previous error so didn't looked at minor mistake but thanks for mentioning it

Comment: I'll do this from next time this is the first question i am posting @PM2Ring 
is there any shortcut to format my whole code after i copy paste my code here instead of adding spaces in front of each line ?

Comment: Yes! To put text into a code block select it and either press the `{}` button at the top of the editing area, or hit ctrl-k on your keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
b.append(rf[q:])
```

appends the list `rf[q:]` to `b` as a single item. But that's not what you really want, because `b` ends up containing sublists of numbers as well as the numbers it's supposed to contain. So you need to add the *contents* of `rf[q:]` to `b`, and you can do that with

```
b.extend(rf[q:])
```

Similar remarks apply to

```
b.append(lf[p:])
```

The error message arises because your code tries to compare numbers in the `lf` and `rf` lists with those sublists you accidentally appended.

Also, as Leon mentions in the comments, you need to do

```
a = sort(a)
```

in the 2nd-last line of your script because your `sort` function doesn't modify the `a` you pass it.

---

BTW, there's no need for you to import the math module in this script: you aren't calling any of its functions or using any of the constants it defines.

Answer (score 1):

When you do either `b.append(rf[q:])` or `b.append(lf[p:])`, you adding a *list* as an element to the list `b`, which looks like it should be a list of integers.